# SQL SELECT WHERE statement. Concatenate attributes against value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, concatenation, where-clause

First yes it's going to be on a silly database that should most likely get remodeled. I'm not able to do that for a long list of reasons at this point.

I have a list of members and they have a trainer which is written in a first and last name (I know you're screaming FK, I just can't)

However a trainer has a username but at this point that's in php so I'm using a string for this example. I want to compare the first and last name without spaces. I believe this is called concatenation. But I can't get it to work and I am unsure as to why.

I have this so far.  (MYSQL)

```
SELECT firstname,lastname 
FROM member
WHERE firstnameTrainer + lastnameTrainer LIKE 'jakethompson'
```

Comment: What type of database is being used?

Comment: what you have should work. what dbms are you using? sqlserver, MySQL, oracle?

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` but not specifying a wildcard?  Are you trying to match that exact name or all those similar to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL, ORACLE

```
SELECT firstname,lastname 
FROM member
WHERE CONCAT(firstnameTrainer,lastnameTrainer) LIKE 'jakethompson'
```

using `LIKE 'jakethompson'` means case insensitive

using `LIKE '%jakethompson%'` means anything what contains this string

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT firstname,lastname 
FROM member
WHERE CONCAT(firstnameTrainer,lastnameTrainer) LIKE '%jakethompson%'
```